# Can we use $(1+x)^n = 1+nx$ where $x\to0$ and $n$ is $1/0$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, binomial-theorem

I was solving a limits questions:

$$\lim_{x\toπ/4} \tan x^{\tan2x}$$

After putting $x = (π/4)+h$ and solving it I got the expression:

$$(1-h/1+h)^{\cot2x} = (1-2h)^{\cot2h}$$

$$(1-2h)^{\cot2h}$$

Now If We solve it using binomial expansion we get $1-(2h\cdot \cot2h)$ using $(1+x)^n=1+nx$,

$$1-2h\cdot\frac{\cos2h}{\sin2h} = 1-\cos2h = 1-1 = 0$$

But If we let this expression as $g$ and take $\ln$ both sides we get:
$$\cot2h\cdot \ln(1-2h)=\ln(g)$$

$\cot2h\cdot(-2h)= -1 = \ln g$

$g = e^{-1}$

In the first method where am I wrong since the answer is coming as $e^{-1}$?

Comment: In the 3rd line, I meant to write cot2h, not cot2x. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is all quite unrigorous. $\cot2h\cdot(-2h)=-1$? No.

Comment: Every time I see $f(x)^{g(x)}$ in a limit context (and many other contexts too), my first thought is to take $\ln$ of both sides, and avoid trying to reason about exponential properties directly.

Comment: @AnotherUser Thanks for giving the links I am new to this site, I will surely check it out.

Comment: @FShrike Is it wrong since 1/tan2h = 1/2h?

Comment: That equation is just generally wrong. $\tan x\neq x$.

Comment: @FShrike But my point is tanx = sinx/cosx and as x tends to 0 sinx=x and cosx=1 hence tanx=x as x tends to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is indeed $\frac 1e$.

Since $\tan(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}$, substitute $y=\tan(x)$ (so $y\to1$ as $x\to\frac\pi4$):

$$\lim_{x\to\frac\pi4} \tan(x)^{\tan(2x)} = \lim_{y\to1} y^{\frac{2y}{1-y^2}}$$

Substitute $y=1-\frac1z$ (so $z\to+\infty$ as $y\to1$ from above). Then

$$\frac{2y}{1-y^2} = \frac1{1-y} - \frac1{1+y} = z + \frac1{\frac1z-2} = z - \frac12 \left(1 + \frac1{2z-1}\right)$$

and so

$$\lim_{y\to1^+} y^{\frac{2y}{1-y^2}} = \lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{\left(1 - \frac1z\right)^z}{\left(1 - \frac1z\right)^{\frac12 \left(1 + \frac1{2z-1}\right)}} = \frac{e^{-1}}1 = \frac1e$$

The numerator approaching $\frac1e$ follows from the definition of the exponential function (let $\xi=-1$),

$$e^\xi = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 + \frac\xi n\right)^n$$

while the denominator approaches $\sqrt{(1-0)^{1+0}}=1$.

As user FShrike points out, we also must consider the limit as $y\to1$ from below, in which case $z\to-\infty$. Then in the limit, we have

$$\lim_{y\to1^-} y^{\frac{2y}{1-y^2}} = \lim_{z\to-\infty} \frac{\left(1-\frac1z\right)^z}{\left(1-\frac1z\right)^{\frac12\left(1+\frac1{2z-1}\right)}} = \lim_{z'\to\infty} \frac{\left(1+\frac1{z'}\right)^{\frac12\left(\frac1{2z'+1}-1\right)}}{\left(1+\frac1{z'}\right)^{z'}} = \frac1{\sqrt{1} e} = \frac1e$$

where $z'=-z$.

The one-sided limits agree, and the result follows.

Comment: Can you please explain what you did in the last step?

Comment: $z\to+\infty$ only provides $y\to1^-$. You need to consider $z\to\pm\infty$ to obtain a two sided limit. Luckily it gives the same answer

Comment: @KartikBhardwaj Added some more details

Comment: @FShrike Come to think of it, I've left that same hole in reasoning on a very similar question in the past, thanks for pointing it out!